# rake aborted! uninitialized constant Logging::Logger::INFO - Namespace collision with WinRM and Albacore

Tags: ruby, logging, rake

Ruby/Rake NOOB and have inherited set of C# projects that use ruby & rake for build/deploy.

The build quit working last week because of an old gem.  In the process of updating all gems to recent versions, I've run into this uninitialized constant problem.

There were no code changes involved and I tried adding "require 'logging'" to setup.rb.

I've been working under the assumption that the problem is in our rake files, but after pounding on this for hours I'm not so sure.  I haven't found anyplace in our code that uses the constant.

Any suggestions or help appreciated.

Windows Server 2008 with Ruby 2.0.0.

gem list output:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

akami (1.2.1)
albacore (0.3.6)
aws-sdk (1.38.0)
bigdecimal (1.2.0)
builder (3.2.2)
bundler (1.6.0)
ffi (1.9.3 x86-mingw32)
gssapi (1.0.3)
gyoku (1.1.1)
httpclient (2.3.4.1)
httpi (0.9.7)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.8.1, 1.7.7)
little-plugger (1.1.3)
logging (1.8.2)
mini_portile (0.5.3)
minitest (4.3.2)
multi_json (1.9.2)
nokogiri (1.6.1 x86-mingw32)
nori (1.1.5)
psych (2.0.0)
rack (1.5.2)
rake (0.9.6)
rdoc (4.0.0)
rubyntlm (0.1.1)
rubyzip (0.9.9)
savon (0.9.5)
test-unit (2.0.0.0)
uuidtools (2.1.4)
wasabi (1.0.0)
win32-service (0.8.4)
winrm (1.1.3)
```

and the rake output:

```
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Logging::Logger::INFO
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rake/ext/module.rb:36:in `const_missing'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/albacore-0.3.6/lib/albacore/support/logging.rb:7:in `initialize'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/albacore-0.3.6/lib/albacore/support/failure.rb:7:in `initialize'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:13:in `initialize'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/nodes/node.rb:35:in `new'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/nodes/node.rb:35:in `to_ruby'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:130:in `load'
C:/build-dir/MV-MB-JOB1/deploy/setup.rb:5:in `block in <top (required)>'
C:/build-dir/MV-MB-JOB1/deploy/setup.rb:5:in `open'
C:/build-dir/MV-MB-JOB1/deploy/setup.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
C:/build-dir/MV-MB-JOB1/deploy/rakefile.rb:15:in `require_relative'
C:/build-dir/MV-MB-JOB1/deploy/rakefile.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rake/application.rb:604:in `raw_load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rake/application.rb:89:in `block in load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rake/application.rb:88:in `load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rake/application.rb:72:in `block in run'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
C:/Ruby200/bin/rake:37:in `<main>'
```

setup.rb:

```
require "yaml"

@environment = ENV["environment"] || "development"
@version = ENV["version"] || "none"
@configuration = File.open(File.join("environment", @environment, "global_config.yml"), "rb") {|f| YAML::load(f)}

@configuration.merge!({:environment => @environment,
                       :version => @version,
                       :repository_path => ENV["repository_path"]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a namespace collision between the WinRM and Albacore gems  AND  WinRM uses the 'logging' gem, Albacore uses 'logger'. Both define Logger.

Using the following command:

```
  rake -f myTest.rb --trace
```

This works:

```
  require "winrm"`
  require "albacore"

  task :default do
  end
```

This does not:

```
  require "albacore"
  require "winrm"

  task :default do
  end
```

Albacore implements lib\albacore\support\logging.rb:

```
require 'logger'

module Logging
  attr_accessor :logger, :current_log_device

  def initialize
    create_logger(STDOUT, Logger::INFO)
    super()
  end

  def log_device=(logdev)
    level = @logger.level
    create_logger(logdev, level)
  end

  .
  .
  .

end
```

WinRm does the following in winrm.rb:

```
require 'date'
require 'kconv' if(RUBY_VERSION.start_with? '1.9') # bug in rubyntlm with ruby 1.9.x
require 'logging'

module WinRM
  Logging.logger.root.level = :info
  Logging.logger.root.appenders = Logging.appenders.stdout
end

require 'winrm/helpers/iso8601_duration'
require 'winrm/soap_provider'
```

Not suggesting this as an appropriate fix, but wrapping the Albacore Logging module in another module, and updating Albacore references to Logging (Albacore::Logging), solves the problem.

Altered lib\albacore\support\logging.rb:

```
module Albacore
    module Logging
        .
        .
        .
     end
end
```

Update:

I opened an Albacore issue.   2.0.0.rc.10, released today, includes a fix for the name collision issue. However, migrating from pre-2.0 Albacore to 2.0.0 is not pain-free because some of the task types have been generalized.    Albacore nunit has been replaced by task_runner.  Albacore msbuild is now simply 'build'.

Answer (score 0):

The conflict can also be solved by moving the `require` down in to the task that needs it, as such:

```
require "albacore"

task :default do
  ...
end

task :some_winrm_task do
  require "winrm"

  ...
end
```